# Django ORM: How can I filter based on an annotation timedelta result

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

I have a model like this:

```
class Interval(models.Model):
   start = models.Datetime()
   end = models.Datetime(null=True)
```

I would like to query all intervals that are larger then 5 minutes.
I'am able to do `intervals=Interval.objects.exclude(end=None).annotate(d=models.F("end")-models.F("start"))`

When I do `intervals[0].d` , I have the interval, which is correct. Now I would like to only get as results the entries where `d` is greater than 5 minutes.

I tried `intervals=Interval.objects.exclude(end=None).annotate(d=models.F("end")-models.F("start")).filter(d__gt=timedelta(0, 300))`, but I get the following error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`. It tries to match the timedelta with a regex of datetime.
`

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `.filter(end__lte=models.F("start")+timedelta(seconds=300))`. Something like this ?

Comment: @duduklein: you probably need to specify that the annotation is a `DurationField`.

Comment: @itzMEonTV this also works, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have to specify the type of the annotated column to Django as a `DurationField`. So you can write it like:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, F, DurationField

delta = ExpressionWrapper(F("end")-F("start"), DurationField())

intervals = (Interval.objects.exclude(end=None)
                             .annotate(d=delta)
                             .filter(d__gt=timedelta(0, 300)))
```

This will construct a query like:

```
SELECT id, start, end TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, start, end) AS `d`
FROM interval
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, start, end) > 300000000
```

But we here thus give Django a hint how to interpret the `d` field (as a `DurationField`), and thus how to "*serialize*" the `timedelta` object).